# Spring Data MongoDB Overriding text index language in a compound index for inner fields

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Here's my document class:

```
@Document(language = "russian")

@CompoundIndexes({        
@CompoundIndex(def = "{'tempId' : 1, 'persons.title' : 'text', 'otherPersons.title' : 'text'}", background = true)})

public class CompanyHistory implements Persistable<String> {

@Id
private String id;

private String tempId;
private List<Person> persons;
private List<OtherPerson> otherPersons;
...
}
```

`Person` and `OtherPerson` contains another two strings, getteres, setters.

Question: how to override language on text index (defaults to English) for inner fields when building compound index? It looks like setting `language` works only with `@TextIndexed` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem (Text index for subentities) and tried to find a way to set `language_override` and `default_language` via `@CompoundIndex`, but nothing worked for me.

Finally I ended with following solution:

```
TextIndexDefinition textIndex = new TextIndexDefinition.TextIndexDefinitionBuilder()
        .withDefaultLanguage("none").withLanguageOverride("dummy")
        .named("text_user_search")
        .onField("user.name")
        .onField("user.mail")
        .build();
mongoTemplate.indexOps(User.class).ensureIndex(textIndex);
```